# Remove elements from array, modify them, place them back in

Tags: ruby, arrays

i have an array of 16 digits:

```
 num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I have to take out all the digits starting with the second to last number counting back every other element to the first element:

```
 every_other_num = num.select.each_with_index{|key, value|value.even?}
 => [1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7]
```

Now, I need to double these digits:

```
 every_other_num_doubled = every_other_num.map {|num|num*2}
 => [2,6,10,14,2,6,10,14]
```

Then, I need to put them back into the original array in place of the ones I took out so the array would look like this:

```
 new_array = [2,2,6,4,10,6,14,8,2,2,6,4,10,6,14,8]
```

It is that last part I cant get. When I put them back in, I am getting a giant array because I am apparently not removing them from the old array. I am thinking the issue lies somewhere in the line of code every_other_num = num.select.each_with_index{|key, value|value.even?} because it isn't actually modifying the original array.

Comment: Will there always be an even number of items?

Comment: @Jordan there will always be 16 digits

Comment: Ah. I was curious because you said "starting with the second to last number counting back..." but if you always have 16 numbers then that's the same as starting with the first number and counting forwards (which is what your code, and @meagar's, does).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's just what the directions said so I copied them word for word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why remove them? That makes no sense, there isn't really a reason I can see that being a requirement. Just double them in-place.

```
num.each_index { |i| nums[i] *= 2 if i.even? }
```

If you *really* want to remove/replace/re-insert, use `zip`/`flatten` to interweave the two arrays back together:

```
['a','b','c'].zip([1, 2, 3]).flatten
=> ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
```

Comment: I really didn't have to take them out and put them back in, I just couldn't think of a way to do it without doing that. This makes more sense.

Comment: If you want to get a new array instead of modifying the original array you can use `num.each_with_index.map {|n,i| i.even? ? n * 2 : n }` (or `...map {|n,i| n * (2 - i % 2) }`.

Answer (score 0):

You took your `num` array and made copies of the even indexed values, `every_other_num`.

You're right, the original array has not been modified.

Why not create yet another copy of `num`, that are the odd indexed values?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
num.map!.with_index {|x,i| i.even? ? 2 * x : x}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

even = false
num.map! { |e| (even=!even) ? 2*e : e }
  #=> [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8]
```

Each element of `num` is passed into the block and doubled if its offset in `num` is even (multiple of 2) and left unchanged if it is odd. `(even=!even)` merely flips the value of `even` from `true` to `false` and from `false` to `true`. When the first element of `num` (at offset `0`) is passed into the block, `even` is `false`, so it becomes `true` when `(even=!even)` is executed. That value is therefore doubled. When the second element of `num` (at offset `1`) is passed to the block, `even` is flipped to `false`, so the value is left unchanged, and so on.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.